# Can data using ajax be made live realtime in CodeIgniter without having to refresh the page view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

i have my code, this data is realtime from database, i want to make it live without refresh the page to display the realtime data.

showDataEmploye();

```
    function showDataEmploye() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('general_data/hr_data/ajaxGetEmploye'); ?>",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                table.clear();
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    table.row.add([
                        item.gender,
                        item.total,
                    ]).draw();
                });
            }
        })
    }
```

[image]

and how to make it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After page load,document.ready you can do following.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() { 
            showDataEmploye()
        }, 1000);

});
```

This will make call every second and it can be pretty much real-time.

Apart from this,on Ajax call success/error/complete you can again call self.

```
function showDataEmploye() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('general_data/hr_data/ajaxGetEmploye'); ?>",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                table.clear();
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    table.row.add([
                        item.gender,
                        item.total,
                    ]).draw();
                });
            showDataEmploye();
            }
        })
    }
```

There may be better answers, these are 2 options.

Though this may not be the best practice, but still it will work...